# Additive Principle using a deck of cards

Tags: probability

Given the question:

> What is the number of cards that are either red cards or face cards?

Because the keyword "or" is given, we must find the Union of Set $A$ and Set $B$, $A$ being red cards, $B$ being face cards. I know that there are $26$ red cards in $1$ deck, and $12$ face cards, I did:

Using the equation:

$$n(A \cup B) = n(A) + n(B) - n(A \cap B)
         = 26 + 12\; - \;?$$

I'm not sure what number goes in for the intersection, the answer I'm looking at says $6$ but I'm not quite sure how they got that?

Comment: You've counted the red face cards twice. In $26+12$. So you need to subtract the number of those.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Correct me if I'm wrong, so the 6 comes from, 3 red face cards such as Queen, King, Jack, + the other 3 red face cards such as Queen, King, Jack? I'm having trouble understanding how you knew to do that from just n(A∩B) unless it's just common sense lol.

Comment: There are two red suits (diamonds and hearts) and three face cards per suit.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks a lot, I understand :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just counting cards.

Red Cards are $\color{red}{\heartsuit}$ and $\color{red}{\diamondsuit}$ of all denominations.  There are 13 cards per suit so that's 26. There are 26 red cards! Twenty-six.

Face Cards are $J, K,$ and $Q$ of all suits.  There are four suits so that's 12. There are 12 face cards! Twelve.

Red Face Cards are $\color{red}{J\heartsuit}, \color{red}{J\diamondsuit},\color{red}{Q\heartsuit}, \color{red}{Q\diamondsuit},\color{red}{K\heartsuit},$ and $\color{red}{K\diamondsuit}$. That's 6, count them 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 red face cards! Six!

*Bahwahhahhah!*

### Crack-a-Boom!

Comment: It might be worth noting that you then subtract the red face cards, since those are the double counted ones. This leaves you with 26+12-6=32.

Comment: And if we were to find the probability, you would just add 52 as a denominator right for every single #, so it would become 26/52 + 12/52 - 6/52?(We don't count jokers in the deck)

Comment: @Xor  That's it; or just do it once for all: $\dfrac{26+12-6}{52}=\dfrac{8}{13}$